# How do I make a simple dropdown menu below a link from the navbar with bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, haml

I'm trying to have a simple dropdown menu where it says "Dropme" but this isn't working.

What do I need to change?

```
.navbar.navbar-inverse{role: 'navigation'}
.navbar-inner
.container-fluid
  %ul.nav.navbar-nav
    %li
      %a{:href => "/"} Home
    %li
      %a{:href => "/unassigned"} Unassigned
    %li
      %a{:href => "/assigned"} Assigned
    %li
      %a{:href => "/agent/all"} Agent
    %li
      %a{:href => "/asnew/joe"} Joe
    %li
      %a{:href => "/asnew/Bob"} Bob
    %li.dropdown
      %a{:href=>"#", :class=>"dropdown-toggle", "data-toggle"=>"dropdown"}Dropme<b class="caret"></b>
      %ul.dropdown-menu
        %li
          %a{:href => "/asnew/Eve"} Eve
        %li
          %a{:href => "/asnew/Gia"} Gia
    %li
      %a{:href => "/note"} Notes
```

Answer (score 0):

I basically added this (again) to the 'li.dropdown' section and it worked.

```
%ul.nav.navbar-nav
```